# Curl OAuth not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use an [OAuth library](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/php/lib/OAuth.php) - it works for yelp but not twitter.

Here is the code:

```
require_once ('lib/OAuth.php'); 
$unsigned_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=test";

$consumer_key = "";
$consumer_secret = "";
$token = "";
$token_secret = "";
$token = new OAuthToken($token, $token_secret);
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$oauthrequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'GET', $unsigned_url);
$oauthrequest->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, $token);
$signed_url = $oauthrequest->to_url();
$ch = curl_init($signed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
print_r($data);
```

This is returning blank code - no errors out anything.  Again, for twitter only, yelp works fine.  Would appreciate help, thanks.